# Jogging or running?

Tags: expressions, terminology

I am telling someone that I am in for sports and spend quite some time outside at a stadium/park moving faster than walking. What is the common word for that? Am I running or jogging? Am I a runner or jogger? Is this somehow related to the professional sport vs hobby?

I've looked through [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jogging):

> Jogging is running at a gentle pace. The definition of jogging as compared with running is not standard. One definition describes jogging as running slower than 6 miles per hour (10 km/h).
>
> Jogging is also distinguished from running by having a wider lateral spacing of foot strikes, creating side-to-side movement that likely adds stability at slower speeds or when coordination is lacking.

I do not feel confident about what it says.

Here is another [version](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Jogging_vs_Running):

> Jogging simply put is running in a leisurely manner that mainly aims towards body fitness. Jogging is also known as roadwork.

This sounds more natural but still leaves the question open. There is a feature-comparison included which states that

> The best timing for jogging is early morning. The best time for running is in the evening/morning, or during a gym session.

This completely screws my understanding. Oh no, I am not into the medicine and I do not wish to discuss the physical aspects. I just wish to get natural at what people call jogging and running.

Are the terms simply interchangeable in a common talk?

Comment: In my experience, *jogging* is a slower, more casual affair, while *running* is more of a hypernym which covers *sprinting*, *jogging* and *atheletics*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey In general I got that idea, thanks. Is there a strict line though? Is it wrong to call someone a runner in a situation? Can that cause a kind of misunderstanding?

Comment: _Jogging_ is generally considered a form of running, albeit at a steady, gentle pace and as a form of physical exercise. Look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @ZverevEugene I would say that *running* can be used in almost any situation while jogging is more specifically slow and casual.

Comment: @Keepthesemind I did look through the dictionary though I did not make up the idea on when to use which term in a common talk not to seem "talking strange".

Comment: *Speedwalking* resembles running (in a weird sort of way), and is almost as fast.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: If you look at someone *running*, they are trying to cover a distance rapidly, and their strides will be long and their motions fluid.

Comment: @HotLicks Poetic.

Comment: Back when I was a runner, it was said (in the magazine *Runner's World*, for example) that if you were taking thirty minutes to go a mile, you were jogging. The minimum cut off point for running  was something like 20 or 25 minutes for a mile depending on how good of a shape you were in, and/or how long you had been a *runner*.  The pace was really the only thing that separated the two activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jogging is what you do just to get exercise, burn calories, and stay loose. The only variable to monitor is approximate distance and just "how you feel". Pace is not important. In a (40-mile / week) training schedule, much of those miles will be "jogging".

When "running" people often record their pace / distance / cadence with a run tracker app. They analyze this later so they can adjust their training plan.

Finally, when you do "*run*" it typically goes like this:
(stretch) --> (a little jogging) --> (run!) --> (a little jogging) --> (stretch)

ps: I am a runner (and jogger).

Comment: I disagree. There are people who *run* for exercise, to burn calories, and to stay loose. Also the pace is important. If you are going one mile in thirty minutes, you're not running.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the determining factor would be whether the activity is done as training for a competition.

If you are participating in competitive running, like Track and Field events at the Olympics, then *running* might be the correct term. If you are running a specific distance in a straight line, you might say that you are *sprinting*.

However, if you just run for fun or exercise, then *jogging* would probably be the better choice.

Comment: I see different people referred to as "runners" and "joggers" by police officers and those people seem quite similar to me. One cannot tell if they are training for a competition or not. Still the terms seem to mean something different.